Why is just watching Trinity fight some cops a violation of the general’s protocols?
In Modal from The Matrix Resurrections (2021), Bugs and Seq watch Trinity fighting cops:

Bugs: Seq, you with me?
Seq: This old code keeps crashing.
Bugs: Your projection's breaking up. Switch to audio.
Seq: Bugs, this is a direct violation of the general's protocols.

Here Seq is referring to their actions of watching Trinity fight
as a violation of the general’s protocols.
Why is just watching Trinity fight some cops a violation of the general’s protocols?
